# PowerShell Move User to different OU in different Domain with Credentials without Quest/ADAM/Cmdlets

Tags: powershell

I'm using

```
[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($context, $idtype, $sam)
```

How do I move this use to a new OU?

I've tried:

```
...
$user_adspath = $user.Properties.adspath
$user_ou = [ADSI]"$user_adspath"
$user_ou.PSBase.MoveTo("LDAP://$target")
```

I recive a "General Access Denied" error. Due to the fact that I need rights. This works though.

```
...
$user.description += " MOVED"
$user.Enabled = $False
$user.Save()
```

Remember this is on a non-2008 server without Quest, ADAM, Cmdlets do not work. The only thing I have working is:

"Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement"

I need something along the lines of this:

```
$user.MoveTo("LDAP://$target")
$user.Save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be on the right track. Do you have write permissions in the target OU? It should be as simple as this:

```
[adsi]$OU="LDAP://OU=Disabled Accounts,OU=Employees,DC=mycompany,DC=local"
[adsi]$User="LDAP://CN=Art Deco,OU=Sales,OU=Employees,DC=mycompany,DC=local"
$user.psbase.Moveto($OU)
```

You don't need to load any assemblies or use anything else.

Comment: It's the permissions I'm having troubles with! I'm logged into the other domain via "[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($context, $idtype, $sam)", this returns "$user" in which I use to do the following commands "$user.description += " MOVED"
$user.Enabled = $False
$user.Save()" with success! Hence why i need a "$user.invoke('ou','LDAP://CN=Art Deco,OU=Sales,OU=Employees,DC=mycompany,DC=local','sAMAccountName=xxxx')" solution!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
[adsi]$dest = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://ou=somwhere,dc=company,dc=local","domain\username","password") 
$user_move = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://cn=user,ou=somehow,dc=company,dc=local","domain\username","password")
$user_move.PSBase.MoveTo($dest)
```

Took awhile!